# Copy Large file from one S3 bucket to another S3 Bucket using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to copy large file (50 GB) from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket. 
Can you please suggest me on this.

I need to create AWS lambda function in AWS.

Comment: Have you tried http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy

Comment: It is helpful only when I have less than 5GB file. But if I need to upload more than 5GB it does not help.

Comment: A standard S3 copy won't work (at least using C#, I can't speak for Python) for big files. In C# I ended up doing a multipart upload using the `CopyPartRequest` object. You specify source/dest buckets and keys, and the byte positions to copy, along with the part number (1 to n). I found that best performance was achieved using ~12 threads to perform the copy.

Comment: If this is all you need one time, just use the aws cli: `aws s3 cp s3://bucketA/filename s3://bucketB/filename`

Comment: Do you have any sample code?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote something like this:

```
int threads = 12;
long fileSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // use exact file size here
InitiateMultipartUploadRequest multipartRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest()
{
    BucketName = "destBucket",
    Key = "destKey"
};
InitiateMultipartUploadResponse multipartResponse = client.InitiateMultipartUpload(multipartRequest);

long minPartSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5 MiB minimum except for last chunk
long maxPartSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024.0; // 5 GiB

long partSize = (long)(fileSize / (double)maxPartSize); // amazon's max chunk size is 5 GiB.
partSize = Math.Max(minPartSize , Math.Min(maxPartSize , partSize));
int parts = (int)Math.Ceiling(fileSize / (double)partSize);
CopyPartResponse[] partsUploaded = new CopyPartResponse[parts];

Parallel.For(0, parts, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, (i) =>
{
    long position = i * partSize;
    long lastPosition = Math.Min(fileSize - 1, (position + partSize - 1));
    var copyPartRequest = new CopyPartRequest()
    {
        DestinationBucket = multipartRequest.BucketName,
        DestinationKey = multipartRequest.Key,
        SourceBucket = "sourceBucket",
        SourceKey = "sourceKey",
        UploadId = multipartResponse.UploadId,
        FirstByte = position,
        LastByte = lastPosition,
        PartNumber = i + 1
    };
    partsUploaded [i] = client.CopyPart(copyPartRequest);
});

CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest()
{
    BucketName = multipartRequest.BucketName,
    Key = multipartRequest.Key,
    UploadId = multipartResponse.UploadId
};
completeRequest.AddPartETags(partsUploaded );
CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeResponse = client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
```

It takes a big file (e.g. 50 GiB) and then calculates the part size to use based on Amazon's maximum and minimums.
Next, it does a Parallel (threaded) for loop with up to 12 threads, to copy the individual parts S3->S3 using the CopyPart functionality of S3.
Finally, it 'completes' the multipart file.

Note: Incomplete multipart files will count towards your bucket usage. You can add a bucket lifecycle policy to delete such files after a given time, or you can use the S3 CLI to discover them.

Comment: what is chunks in Parallel.For(0, chunks, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = threads }, (i) =>
{

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to read `parts` - I've corrected it now. I changed the variable names when I posted the answer so that it was a little more consistent with AWS .

Comment: I went with something similar but without using Parallel.For as it doesn't play nicely with async methods. I was using client.CopyPartAsync (looks like the version of the S3 client I was using doesn't have a non-async version of this method).

Comment: @jackofallcode Nowadays ForEachAsync exists in parallel, so you should be able to still use parallel if so desired.

Answer (score 2):

The [boto3 Amazon S3 `copy()` command](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) can copy large files:

> Copy an object from one S3 location to another.
>
> This is a managed transfer which will perform a multipart copy in multiple threads if necessary.

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

Comment: Lambda can upload only 1536 MB in one post and its Max Timeout is 5 min 59 sec. So that they provide us the functionality of Mutipart upload. I have code in using boto. But right now we are using boto3.

Comment: If a file is large it uses a different method to upload (something like multipart upload).  It requires a separate permission, Your user probably doesn't have permission to use that function.

Comment: It doesn't work. Copying of file large than 5Gb required multipart.

Answer (score 0):

I am done with this problem. I am posting my solution so that it can help you.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using Amazon.S3;

using Amazon.S3.Model;


namespace s3.amazon.com.docsamples
{
    class CopyObjectUsingMPUapi
    {

        static string sourceBucket    = "*** Source bucket name ***";
        static string targetBucket    = "*** Target bucket name ***";
        static string sourceObjectKey = "*** Source object key ***";
        static string targetObjectKey = "*** Target object key ***";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            // List to store upload part responses.
            List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();

            List<CopyPartResponse> copyResponses = new List<CopyPartResponse>();
            InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest =
                   new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
                       {
                           BucketName = targetBucket,
                           Key = targetObjectKey
                       };

            InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
                s3Client.InitiateMultipartUpload(initiateRequest);
            String uploadId = initResponse.UploadId;

            try
            {
                // Get object size.
                GetObjectMetadataRequest metadataRequest = new GetObjectMetadataRequest
                    {
                         BucketName = sourceBucket,
                         Key        = sourceObjectKey
                    };

                GetObjectMetadataResponse metadataResponse = 
                             s3Client.GetObjectMetadata(metadataRequest);
                long objectSize = metadataResponse.ContentLength; // in bytes

                // Copy parts.
                long partSize = 5 * (long)Math.Pow(2, 20); // 5 MB

                long bytePosition = 0;
                for (int i = 1; bytePosition < objectSize; i++)
                {

                    CopyPartRequest copyRequest = new CopyPartRequest
                        {
                            DestinationBucket = targetBucket,
                            DestinationKey = targetObjectKey,
                            SourceBucket = sourceBucket,
                            SourceKey = sourceObjectKey,
                            UploadId = uploadId,
                            FirstByte = bytePosition,
                            LastByte = bytePosition + partSize - 1 >= objectSize ? objectSize - 1 : bytePosition + partSize - 1,
                            PartNumber = i
                        };

                    copyResponses.Add(s3Client.CopyPart(copyRequest));

                    bytePosition += partSize;
                }
                CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest =
                      new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
                          {
                              BucketName = targetBucket,
                              Key = targetObjectKey,
                              UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
                          };

                completeRequest.AddPartETags(copyResponses);
                CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse = s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        // Helper function that constructs ETags.
        static List<PartETag> GetETags(List<CopyPartResponse> responses)
        {
            List<PartETag> etags = new List<PartETag>();
            foreach (CopyPartResponse response in responses)
            {
                etags.Add(new PartETag(response.PartNumber, response.ETag));
            }
            return etags;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a copy paste from...  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjctsUsingLLNetMPUapi.html